# nodejs passport-azure-ad redirect to failureRedirect

Tags: node.js, passport-azure-ad

Hello i am trying to understand and apply "passport-azure-ad" function which i found on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node?tutorial-step=1 to my own web applicaton.

Instead of "hbs"template engine what they use in the tutorial i use "jade". I registered the application in Azure. When running the web-application I and noticed that the **signin** function is working (redirected to the login page of Microsoft to enter my credentials). But when i leave the credentials page it returns to the **http://localhost:3000/error** instead of **http://localhost:3000/succes ** what i expected.

Can you please help me?

Below i put the javascript files:

**app.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var session = require('express-session');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var passport = require('passport');
var OIDCStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').OIDCStrategy;
var graph = require('./graph');

// Configure simple-oauth2
const oauth2 = require('simple-oauth2').create({
  client: {
    id: process.env.OAUTH_APP_ID,
    secret: process.env.OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD
  },
  auth: {
    tokenHost: process.env.OAUTH_AUTHORITY,
    authorizePath: process.env.OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT,
    tokenPath: process.env.OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT
  }
});

// Configure passport

// In-memory storage of logged-in users
// For demo purposes only, production apps should store
// this in a reliable storage
var users = {};

// Passport calls serializeUser and deserializeUser to
// manage users
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  // Use the OID property of the user as a key
  users[user.profile.oid] = user;
  done (null, user.profile.oid);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  done(null, users[id]);
});

// Callback function called once the sign-in is complete
// and an access token has been obtained
async function signInComplete(iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) {
  if (!profile.oid) {
    return done(new Error("No OID found in user profile."), null);
  }

  try{
    const user = await graph.getUserDetails(accessToken);

    if (user) {
      // Add properties to profile
      profile['email'] = user.mail ? user.mail : user.userPrincipalName;
      console.info(users)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    done(err, null);
  }

  // Create a simple-oauth2 token from raw tokens
  let oauthToken = oauth2.accessToken.create(params);

  // Save the profile and tokens in user storage
  users[profile.oid] = { profile, oauthToken };
  return done(null, users[profile.oid]);
}

// Configure OIDC strategy
passport.use(new OIDCStrategy(
  {
    identityMetadata: `${process.env.OAUTH_AUTHORITY}${process.env.OAUTH_ID_METADATA}`,
    clientID: process.env.OAUTH_APP_ID,
    responseType: 'code id_token',
    responseMode: 'form_post',
    redirectUrl: process.env.OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI,
    allowHttpForRedirectUrl: true,
    clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD,
    validateIssuer: false,
    passReqToCallback: false,
    scope: process.env.OAUTH_SCOPES.split(' ')
  },
  signInComplete
));

//setup routes
//require('./routes/routes')(app, passport);

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var authRouter = require('./routes/auth');

var app = express();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'your_secret_value_here',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  unset: 'destroy'
}));

// Flash middleware
app.use(flash());



// Set up local vars for template layout
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // Read any flashed errors and save
  // in the response locals
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error_msg');

  // Check for simple error string and
  // convert to layout's expected format
  var errs = req.flash('error');
  for (var i in errs){
    res.locals.error.push({message: 'An error occurred', debug: errs[i]});
  }

  next();
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // Set the authenticated user in the
  // template locals
  if (req.user) {
    res.locals.user = req.user.profile;
  }
  next();
});

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/auth', authRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**auth.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET auth callback. */
router.get('/signin',
  function  (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect',
      {
        response: res,
        prompt: 'login',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: true,
        successRedirect: '/'
      }
    )(req,res,next);
  }
);

router.post('/callback',
  function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect',
      {
        response: res,
        failureRedirect: '/Error',
        failureFlash: true,
        successRedirect: '/Succes'
      }
    )(req,res,next);
  }
);
```

**graph.js**

```
var graph = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client');
require('isomorphic-fetch');

module.exports = {
  getUserDetails: async function(accessToken) {
    const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);

    const user = await client.api('/me').get();
    return user;
  }
};

function getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken) {
  // Initialize Graph client
  const client = graph.Client.init({
    // Use the provided access token to authenticate
    // requests
    authProvider: (done) => {
      done(null, accessToken);
    }
  });

  return client;
}
```